# BST insertion and Indore traversal doesn't print anything what is wrong with it

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

**This is my code for BST insertion and inoder transversal.**
I have written this code for binary search tree insertion and inoder transversal.
Code get executed and return to idle.

```
class Bst {
    Node Root;
    Bst(){
        this.Root = null;
    }
    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node left,right;
        Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }
    }
    Node Binsert(Node root, int a){
        if(root == null){
            root = new Node(a);
            return root;
        }
        else if(root.data >= a){
            root.left = Binsert(root.left, a);
        }
        else{
            root.right = Binsert(root.right, a);
        }
        return root;
    }
    void Inoder(Node root){
        if (root != null) {
            Inoder(root.left);
            System.out.println(root.data);
            Inoder(root.right);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bst b = new Bst();
        b.Binsert(b.Root, 6);
        b.Binsert(b.Root, 3);
        b.Binsert(b.Root, 5);
        b.Binsert(b.Root, 7);
        b.Binsert(b.Root, 1);
        b.Binsert(b.Root, 2);
        b.Binsert(b.Root, 4);
        b.Binsert(b.Root, 8);
        b.Binsert(b.Root, 9);
        b.Inoder(b.Root);
    }
}
```

**This code I found online what's the different why my code not printing anything.**
But this code which i found online work fine but why that so.

```
public class Main {

    public class Node {
        public int data;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }

    }
    public Node root;

    public Main() {
        this.root = null;
    }
    
    public void insert(int newData) {
        this.root = insert(root, newData);
    }

    public Node insert(Node root, int newData) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(newData);
            return root;
        }
        else if (root.data >= newData) {
            root.left = insert(root.left, newData);
        } else {
            root.right = insert(root.right, newData);
        }
        return root;
    }

    public void inorder() {
        Inorder(root);
    }

    public void Inorder(Node root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        Inorder(root.left);
        System.out.print(root.data + " ");
        Inorder(root.right);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main bst = new Main();
        bst.insert(2);
        bst.insert(4);
        bst.insert(1);
        bst.insert(3);
        bst.insert(5);
        bst.inorder();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Compare the insert function. You return the new node but did not assign it to anything, while they update the class instance itself.

Comment: Hint:  make the root of Bst private and make the Node class private.  They would help you move closer to the same solution.  You will need to capture the changed tree which you currently not doing.  So, no matter what changes are made to the tree, the tree is not updated.